# Problemas con Login en php

Tags: php, mysqli

Bueno, estoy tratando de realizar un login para un página el cual al validar el usuario redireccione a una nueva página,el problema es que cunado ingreso los datos para ingresar, los cuales estoy completamente seguro existe en la base de datos, siempre me manda la respuesta que los datos son incorrectos. El código php que estoy usando para validar el usuario a ingresar es éste:

```
<?php   
//Conectamos a la base de datos
require('conexion.php');

//Obtenemos los datos del formulario de acceso
$userPOST = $_POST["nombre"]; 
$passPOST = $_POST["pass"];

//Filtro anti-XSS
$userPOST = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $userPOST));
$passPOST = htmlspecialchars(mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $passPOST));

//Definimos la cantidad máxima de caracteres
//Esta comprobación se tiene en cuenta por si se llegase a modificar el "maxlength" del formulario
//Los valores deben coincidir con el tamaño máximo de la fila de la base de datos
$maxCaracteresUsername = "50";
$maxCaracteresPassword = "18";

//Si los input son de mayor tamaño, se "muere" el resto del código y muestra la respuesta correspondiente 
if(strlen($userPOST) > $maxCaracteresUsername && strlen($passPOST) > $maxCaracteresPassword) 
    {
        die('Los datos exceden la extensión máxima de caracteres.');
    };

if(strlen($userPOST) > $maxCaracteresUsername) 
    {
        die('El nombre de usuario no puede superar los '.$maxCaracteresUsername.' caracteres.');
    };

if(strlen($passPOST) > $maxCaracteresPassword) 
    {
        die('La contraseña no puede superar los '.$maxCaracteresPassword.' caracteres.');
    };
//Escribimos la consulta necesaria
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM `acopiadores` WHERE nombre='".$userPOST."'";

//Obtenemos los resultados
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
$datos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

//Guardamos los resultados del nombre de usuario
//y de la contraseña de la base de datos 
$userBD = $datos['nombre'];
$passwordBD = $datos['pass'];

//Comprobamos si los datos son correctos
if($userBD == $userPOST and password_verify($passPOST, $passwordBD))
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $datos['nombre'];
    $_SESSION['estado'] = 'Autenticado';
    header("Location: intacopiador.php"); 

//Si los datos no son correctos, o están vacíos, muestra un error 
} 
else if ( $userBD != $userPOST || $userPOST == "" || $passPOST == "" || !password_verify($passPOST, $passwordBD) )
{
    die ('<script>$(".acceso").val("");</script>
    Los datos de acceso son incorrectos.');
} 
else 
{
    die('Error');
};
```

?>

No voy a mentir, soy algo trenco en programación web y estoy teniendo problemas algo que posiblemente sea muy sencillo. 
La parte HTML del formulario para ingreso es ésta:

```
<div id="mensaje" style="border:1px solid #CCC; padding:10px; width:400px"></div>
        </center>

        <center>
          <div class="container #ffffff white" style="width:300px">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            <label for="Usuario">Nombre de Usuario: <i class="material-icons right">assignment_ind</i></label> 
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control" style="width:200px;height:15px">
          </div>
        </center>

            <div> <img src="img/separate.png" width="250" height="150"  alt="Image" class="responsive-img"> </div>

        <center>
          <div class="container #ffffff white" style="width:300px">
            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
            <label for="contra">Contraseña:<i class="material-icons right">lock</i></label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" class="form-control" style="width:200px;height:15px">
          </div>
        </center> 

      <center> 
        <div class="text-center">
          <button class="btn indigo accent-4" type="submit" value="submit"  name="Validar">Iniciar Sesión<i class="material-icons right">vpn_key</i></button>
        </div> 
      </center>
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

En el mismo archivo estoy usando el siguiente script para mandarlo a el archivo "acceso.php" para que valide el inicio de sesión:

```
<script>
var mensaje = $("#mensaje");
mensaje.hide();

$("#login").on("submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("login"));

    $.ajax({
    url: "acceso.php", 
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "HTML",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false

    }).done(function(echo){
    if (echo !== "") {
      mensaje.html(echo);
      mensaje.slideDown(500);
    } else {
      window.location.replace("");
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Lamento las molestias y gracias

Edit: Bueno, gracias los que comentaron ya no me da el error de decir que los datos son incorrectos a pesar de que ingreso datos que sé que están en la base de datos, pero al esperar a que me redireccione a la siguiente página obtengo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que se encarga de verificar el login quedó así:

```
<?php   
//Conectamos a la base de datos
require('conexion.php');

//Obtenemos los datos del formulario de acceso
$userPOST = $_POST["nombre"]; 
$passPOST = $_POST["pass"];

$maxCaracteresUsername = "50";
$maxCaracteresPassword = "18";

//Si los input son de mayor tamaño, se "muere" el resto del código y muestra la respuesta correspondiente 
if(strlen($userPOST) > $maxCaracteresUsername && strlen($passPOST) > $maxCaracteresPassword) 
    {
        die('Los datos exceden la extensión máxima de caracteres.');
    };

if(strlen($userPOST) > $maxCaracteresUsername) 
    {
        die('El nombre de usuario no puede superar los '.$maxCaracteresUsername.' caracteres.');
    };

if(strlen($passPOST) > $maxCaracteresPassword) 
    {
        die('La contraseña no puede superar los '.$maxCaracteresPassword.' caracteres.');
    };
//Escribimos la consulta necesaria
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM `acopiadores` WHERE nombre='".$userPOST."'";

//Obtenemos los resultados
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
$datos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

//Guardamos los resultados del nombre de usuario
//y de la contraseña de la base de datos 
$userBD = $datos['nombre'];
$passwordBD = $datos['pass'];

//Comprobamos si los datos son correctos
if($userBD == $userPOST and $passwordBD == $passPOST)
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $datos['nombre'];
    $_SESSION['estado'] = 'Autenticado';
    header("Location: intacopiador.php"); 

//Si los datos no son correctos, o están vacíos, muestra un error 
} 
else if ( $userBD != $userPOST || $userPOST == "" || $passPOST == "" || $passwordBD != $passPOST )
{

    die ('<script>$(".acceso").val("");</script>
    Los datos de acceso son incorrectos.');

} 
else 
{
    die('Error');
};
```

?>

Y el código de la página a la que quiero redirecciconar es éste:

```
<?php

session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);


if(isset($_SESSION['usuario']) and $_SESSION['estado'] == 'Autenticado') {
  include('intacopiador.php');
  die();
} else {
  include('logeo.php');
  die();
};

include('conexion.php');
require('sesiones.php');
```

?>

Esa es la parte del PHP no creo que sea necesario poner el HTML, pero si hace falta edito, gracias.

Comment: Probaste `password_verify($passPOST, $passwordBD)==true`

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Generalmente veo que en código como el tuyo el uso de `htmlspecialchars` y de `mysqli_real_escape_string` impide el funcionamiento ... y además, no impide una posible inyección SQL, que es lo que hay que proteger aquí. No haces nada con esas funciones si luego tú pasas la consulta así: `$consulta = "SELECT * FROM acopiadores WHERE nombre='".$userPOST."'";`, pues el hecho de enviar el valor `$userPOST` es el verdadero peligro aquí. Tendrías que renunciar a las dos funciones de escape e implementar consultas preparadas...

Comment: ... por otra parte, no veo el sentido de usar `password_verify` en el segundo `if`, cuando se supone que si no pasó el primer `if` es porque ya el password fue verificado. También, puedes depurar tus variables, para revisar lo que está ocurriendo, especialmente `$userBD`, `$passwordBD` y las demás.

Comment: Si, y estoy recibiendo la misma respuesta.

Comment: Ya depuré las 4 variables las de las consultas y las de user y password, todas tienen los datos que deben ser y la consulta si es hecha correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa la documentacion de la funcion password_verify() http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php ahi veras que la funcion consume un pass y un hash para validar que este correcto; tu estas pasando 2 passwords, lo cual hace que la funcion de resultado negativo y por eso tu codigo no funciona

si tus pass no tienen hash bastara con compararlas para que de el resultado esperado

```
 if($userBD == $userPOST and $passPOST==$passwordBD))
   {
     // verdadero

   }
```

Comment: No tengo hash en el pass y con la comprobación directa que tu dices me sigue mostrando el mismo resultado, que los datos son incorrectos.

Comment: saludos cambia el else if ( $userBD != $userPOST || $userPOST == "" || $passPOST == "" || !password_verify($passPOST, $passwordBD) )
{
    die ('<script>$(".acceso").val("");</script>
    Los datos de acceso son incorrectos.');
} quita la parte de password_verify esa no te funcionara por que esa funciona solo con hash  y pon mejor esta verificacion $passPOST!=$passwordBD

Comment: Bueno, modifiqué a como tu dices y al cambiar eso ya no me muestra el mensaje de "los datos de acceso son incorrectos" simplemente me muestra el mensaje de error y sigue sin permitirme el acceso.

Comment: que mensaje de error te aparece?

Comment: el simple mensaje de error que está en el final del script php que valida el inicio de sesión
else 
{
    die('Error');
};

Comment: modificaste tambien el if para quitar lo de password_verify?

Comment: los 2 están sin el verify

Comment: puedes volver a editar tu pregunta para que pongas el codigo como quedo editado? al final de tu pregunta actual pon EDIT: y pon tu codigo

Comment: Ya edite ya que obtuve un resultado nuevo

Comment: antes del  if($userBD == $userPOST and $passwordBD == $passPOST) has un echo a las 4 variables para ver si estan iguales aun

Comment: ya lo hice y las variables vienen con los datos correctos

Comment: aun tienes problemas con el codigo?

Comment: Si, los datos están bien, ya me verifica bien como son los datos y todo eso pero ahora cuando debería redireccionar a la siguiente página me muestra éste error:

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\just\intacopiador.php on line 111

Y esa línea que dice es el cierre de la etiqueta HTML

Comment: por el tipo error es relacionado a la memoria de php no tienes algun ciclo que se pudiera estar yendo al infinito o que alguna consulta de base de datos  no se termine de procesar?

Comment: Las consultas se terminan de procesar correctamente de tener algún ciclo infinito no lo sé

Comment: Tendrias que ver parte por parte de tu php para ver que esta haciendo que se desborde la memoria

Comment: el archivo php que da error no es el mismo que pusiste en la pregunta verdad?

Comment: es el último que puse en el edit

Comment: pon el código del archivo intacopiador.php ahi es donde esta tronando tu pagina